# Divisibility of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let the sequence $x_n$ be defined by $x_1=1,\,x_{n+1}=x_n+x_{[(n+1)/2]},$ where $[x]$ is the integer part of a real number $x$. This is [A033485](https://oeis.org/A033485). How to prove or disprove that 4 is not a divisor of any its term? The problem belongs to math folklore. As far as I know it, [M. Kontsevich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxim_Kontsevich) authors that.

Comment: How is $x_0$ defined?  Your recurrence gives $x_2=x_1+x_{[1/2]}=x_1+x_0$.

Comment: @ Nicholas R. Peterson: Thank you. It has been fixed.

Comment: Assuming n>=1 and using the given equation I could find the elements to be 1,2,3,5,7.....and the difference between them is 1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5...... which is the repetition of each element of the series itself....Interesting series but how to find the nth term in terms of n?

Comment: Up to A033485 , a closed form of $x_n$ is not known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $u_n=x_n\bmod 4$, and let $\oplus$ denote addition modulo $4$. We have the recurrences

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
u_{2n}&=u_{2n-1}\oplus u_n\\
u_{2n+1}&=u_{2n}\oplus u_n\;,
\end{align*}\right.$$

and the first few values are $u_1=1,u_2=2,u_3=3$, and $u_4=1$. The desired result is an immediate corollary of the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** For all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $u_{4n}=u_n$, $u_{4n+1},u_{4n+3}\in\{1,3\}$, and $u_{4n+2}=2$.

The proof is by induction on $n$. For $n>1$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
u_{4n}&=u_{4n-1}\oplus\color{blue}{u_{2n}}\\
&=\color{blue}{u_{4n-1}}\oplus u_{2n-1}\oplus u_n\\
&=\color{blue}{u_{4n-2}}\oplus 2u_{2n-1}\oplus u_n\\
&=\color{blue}{u_{4n-3}}\oplus 3u_{2n-1}\oplus u_n\\
&=\color{blue}{u_{4n-4}}\oplus u_{2n-2}\oplus 3u_{2n-1}\oplus u_n\\
&=\color{blue}{u_{n-1}\oplus u_{2n-2}}\oplus 3u_{2n-1}\oplus u_n\\
&=\color{blue}{4u_{2n-1}}\oplus u_n\\
&=x_n\;,
\end{align*}$$

where on each line I’ve highlighted in blue the term(s) to be manipulated to get the next line.

Then we have

$$\begin{align*}
&u_{4n+1}=u_{4n}\oplus u_{2n}=u_n\oplus u_{2n}=u_{2n+1}\in\{1,3\}\;,\\
&u_{4n+2}=u_{4n+1}\oplus u_{2n+1}=u_{2n+1}\oplus u_{2n+1}=2\;,\text{ and}\\
&u_{4n+3}=u_{4n+2}\oplus u_{2n+1}=2\oplus u_{2n+1}\in\{1,3\}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the induction goes through.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Thank you for the interest to the question. I need some time to think about that.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: +1. Very nice.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Strongly and clearly.

Comment: @user64494: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by induction that modulo $4$,
$y_n = (x_n, (x_{2n-1}, x_{2n}, x_{2n+1}))$ is always one of the following quadruplets :
$(1,(1,2,3)) ;  (2,(1,3,1)) ; (2,(3,1,3)) ;  (3,(3,2,1))$
($x_n$ and $x_{2n-1}$ determine the other two values so this is also saying that $(x_n,x_{2n-1})$ can never be $(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)$ or $(3,2)$)

We check that $y_1 = (1,(1,2,3))$.

If $y_n = (1,(1,2,3))$ then since $1$ can only be followed by $2$ or $3$, either $x_{n+1} = 2$ and $y_{n+1} = (2,(3,1,3))$, either $x_{n+1} = 3$ and $y_{n+1} = (3,(3,2,1))$.
If $y_n = (3,(3,2,1))$ then since $3$ can only be followed by $1$ or $2$, either $x_{n+1} = 1$ and $y_{n+1} = (1,(1,2,3))$, either $x_{n+1} = 2$ and $y_{n+1} = (2,(1,3,1))$.
If $x_n = 2$ then $n = 2k$ and $y_k$ is $(1,(1,2,3))$ or $(3,(3,2,1))$.
In the first case we get $y_{n-1} = (1,(1,2,3)), y_n = (2,(3,1,3))$ and $y_{n+1} = (3,(3,2,1))$
In the other case we get $y_{n-1} = (3,(3,2,1)), y_n = (2,(1,3,1))$ and $y_{n+1} = (1,(1,2,3))$

---

Shape those quadruplet as a small triangle piece.
Here is the picture of the possible ways those pieces can interact : From the possible top and left pieces (determined by $x_n,x_{2n-1},x_{4n-3}$) we compute the other values and see that the next two pieces are still of the $4$ possible kind.

[image]

Comment: @ mercio: Thank you for the interest to the question. I need some time to think about that.

Comment: @mercio: Could you explain how you get $y_{n+1}$ from $y_{n}$ in your first case? Why is the first entry 3 and not 1?

Comment: @ mercio: You wrote "In the first case we get $y_{n-1} = (1,(1,2,3)), y_n = (2,(3,1,3)) $ and $y_{n+1} = (3,(3,2,1)) $". Could you explain that place in detail?

Comment: @ mercio: I find your idea interesting, but I don't find your exposition transparent.